# Is it possible to install Yaru (Communitheme) on Lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

I was searching everywhere for this, but I was wondering if there is a way to install the new Yaru theme on Lubuntu 18.10, without having to build from source?

I was thinking that I could simply install the Communitheme snap that I found on Discover (the Lubuntu software center), but I didn't know what to do next.

I know that Yaru is a GTK theme as well, so I thought it would be easy to just install the Communitheme snap, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT 1: 
[image: Screenshot of Lubuntu Appearance Settings]

As per the attached screenshot, I realize that Lubuntu can work with GTK themes, but I'm a little confused as to how to do this...

EDIT 2:

[image: Screenshot of Lubuntu Login Screen]
I used the terminal to install the Snap version of Communitheme and did not get any errors. However, I do not know how to choose the Communitheme session; the only options when selecting the gear at the upper left corner of the screenshot above are "Lubuntu Session," "LXQt Desktop Session," and "Openbox Session."

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10 is lxqt, which uses qt-styles and lxqt themes, gtk themes could eventually be set for gtk-gui programs

Comment: You're right, cipricus. When I said "everywhere" I was referring to the help forums (making sure I didn't post a duplicate question).

Comment: So @cipricus, are you saying I cannot put Yaru on Lubuntu because Yaru is a GTK theme and Lubuntu uses QT?

Comment: @Kulfy I just ran the command and restarted, but I'm not very familiar with Lubuntu so I don't know how to toggle Communitheme. I checked the Appearance settings again (image attached in above description) but there is still no sign of "Yaru" or "Communitheme." But I know I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Yes, and it said (paraphrasing:) "NOTE: [something] Reboot" and it said "Installed Communitheme by DidRocks" Sorry I can't remember it word-for-word because I rebooted the machine.

Comment: @Kulfy Please see my updated question with an additional screenshot above. And thanks for all of your help!

Comment: That is all that I see.

Comment: The link I had initially posted was about 18.04. In 18.10 Yaru theme is in the repos. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install the Yaru theme in Lubuntu 18.10

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk
```

Unlike  18.04 which used LXDE, Lubuntu 18.10 has a Qt desktop, LXQt. That means that, like in Plasma/KDE (which I'm using right now myself, although I have used LXQt untill recently), **the GTK themes like Yaru will not cover most of your desktop, but only the appearance of applications that have a GTK gui**, like Firefox, Deadbeef, Audacious, Disks, uGet, etc.

If that is what you want, install Yaru as said above and enable it for both GTK2 and GTK3 from settings in your first posted image.

---

The other parts in the appearance of the LXQt desktop are:

- the Qt-styles: covering the full texture of all Qt applications (especially the file manager, and specifically setting the **light or dark** look ) - more about that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468709/32012).
- the LXQt theme: covering mostly the panel
- the Openbox settings: covering windows
- the icons

---

Unlike in Plasma settings, in LXQt settings there is no option for icons in GTK applications, as you can see. I think what happens is that GTK apps will use the main icon set.

Yaru package includes a dark theme only for its GTK3 version though, which might be a problem if you use a dark qt-style (like Breeze Dark, or Kvantum Dark) with icons adapted to those (that is: light icons): the GTK2 apps will have light theme with light icons. So, if you chose Yaru theme you should **EITHER** avoid using dark Qt-styles **OR** GTK2 applications.

In Plasma 5 there is an option for GTK themes where you can chose "prefer dark GTK3 theme", which then makes the gtk2 apps use a dark theme too. But that option seems absent in LXQt.

There are other good GTK themes both dark and light that can be installed in LXQt, the problem with GTK theming in a Qt desktop is one of **integration**.

The most obvious **good integration of GTK application in a Qt desktop these days is provided by the Breeze qt-styles with the Breeze GTK themes**. As you already use the Breeze qt-style, you can use the Breeze GTK package too, which has light and dark themes both for GTK 2 and 3.

```
sudo apt install breeze-gtk-theme
```